# Open Outlook using VBA in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to open Outlook when a button is clicked in MS Access, I have the following code which I have gathered online and after tinkering with it it is still not working. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command56_Click()
Dim obj
On Error Resume Next
Set obj = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If obj Is Nothing Then Set obj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What does 'not working' mean - error message, wrong results, nohting happens? Setting an object variable does not open the application for user to work with. If you just want to open the application for user to interact with then review https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/647774-visual-basic-applications-code-open-outlook.html. If you want to use VBA to manipulate an Outlook object to automate sending email then your code is a beginning.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call *GetObject*. If Outlook is loaded, it will create a reference to it and if not, it will be loaded. It will not create a new instance though.

```
Private Sub Command56_Click()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        obj.Visible = True

    'do work


    obj.Quit  '<-- This will close Outlook
    Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this procedure:

```
    Private Sub OpenOutlook(emailAddress As String)
        Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
        Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
        Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

        ' Create the Outlook session.
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        ' Create the message.
        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With objOutlookMsg
            ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
            .Subject = "ISF"
            .Body = "This is the body of the message." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            .Recipients.Add (emailAddress)
            ' Add attachments to the message.
            Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add("\\sql\images\" & Forms![WebQADocumentReview].FileName)

            .Display
        End With
        Set objOutlook = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

But you can’t use similar code with Outlook due to how Outlook opens which is quite different from other Office products. Sometimes it is important to know that Outlook is open, for example to be sure that your mails created with VBA code are sent and not waiting in your outbox.

The code below is created by MVP Ben Clothier and can either retrieve an open instance of Outlook or open Outlook if it is closed. This uses a ‘self-healing object’ approach for returning an instance of Outlook.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Declarations

```
Dim g_olApp As Object
```

Create the below Subroutine

```
Private Sub fireOutlook()
    Dim olShellVal As Long

    On Error GoTo FIREOUTLOOK_ERR
    Set g_olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") ' If outlook is open will create obj
    ' If closed this will goto the error handler and then resume
    If g_olApp Is Nothing Then ' This checks if object was created
        olShellVal = Shell("OUTLOOK", vbNormalNoFocus) ' Opens Outlook
        Set g_olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") ' Creates the Object
    End If
FIREOUTLOOK_EXIT:
    Exit Sub
FIREOUTLOOK_ERR:
    If g_olApp Is Nothing Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error Number: " & Err.Number
    End If
    GoTo FIREOUTLOOK_EXIT
End Sub
```

Once this is complete the global object can be used in any code involving outlook just make sure to call the fireOutlook subroutine first.